# Conditional assignation with mutate and ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr

Having this kind of data (see below), I try to create a new column `IRISCOM` based on a conditional test with mutate().

```
COMMUNE|IRIS|NB
35360|353600101|45
35361|ZZZZZZ|72
```

I have tried with `data=mutate(data, IRISCOM= ifelse(IRIS == "ZZZZZZZZZ", COMMUNE, IRIS))`

It writes correctly COMMUNE but does write `1` in place of IRIS code as expected.

I've tried some more experimentations with no success.

Comment: That's because `IRIS` is a `factor`; the numeric value corresponding to factor level `353600101` is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `factor` issue (see my comment above) we can do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(IRISCOM = ifelse(IRIS == "ZZZZZZ", COMMUNE, IRIS))
#  COMMUNE      IRIS NB   IRISCOM
#1   35360 353600101 45 353600101
#2   35361    ZZZZZZ 72     35361
```

---

### Sample data

```
data <- read.table(text =
    "COMMUNE|IRIS|NB
35360|353600101|45
35361|ZZZZZZ|72", header = T, sep = "|")
```